Light Switch wiring for 3 gang single pole and 1 gang single pole switch below on wall
At my entry I have a 4 gang group of switches and then a single gang switch right below it on the wall. The far left switch is on a different breaker so I have it wired and working. The 3 switches on the right is what I need some guidance for. The first switch (from left to right) I have no idea what it powers. (On one attempt of wiring all the switches, if this switch was on, it provided power to the switch below. I think I just had it wired incorrectly.) The next switch is a single pole turning on a chandelier. The 4th controls a single canned light on the front porch.
The switch below the 4 gang controls two light fixtures in the front of the house.
My goal is for the Chandelier, can porch light and front dual light fixtures to be on smart switches. Before I had removed all the switches, I had the dual light fixtures all working and scheduled with the smart switch.
Now I can't seem to make heads nor tails of the wiring.


Any chance the unknown switch powers a wall outlet?

Unfortunately I imagine it possibly does, but never took the time before I destroyed this to figure out which outlet it possibly controls.
